# AWS : Security groups . When saving inbound rule, IP address changes automatically after saving

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to add my IP address in the inbound rule in security groups in AWS .

After I hit save button it changes the IP address that I saved.

Example if I am saving the IP address like 123.3.23.123 it changes it to 123.3.23.117.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses must be specified in [CIDR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). If you would like to add a single IP address to your security group, use a `/32` suffix.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for message. I have it this in this format itself. I did my IP in the selection and it took 32 automatically. But I am not able to access any port with that rule. I am not even able to access the public dns here.